# Trying to convert a string into json object

Tags: string, json

I have a string in the following format :

```
      {
       "payload" : {
                   "name1 " : "value",
                   "Dir" : "<users>/<userid>/<YYYY>/<MM>/<DD>",
                   "file" : "username<userid>.json",
                   "userid" : <int>
                   },
       "PK_id" : "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
      }
```

And I am using this code to convert the string into json object :

```
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(jsonString.substring(0));
```

But I am getting this error for back slashes used in directory location and file name :

```
      Exception in thread "main" org.json.JSONException: Expected a ',' or '}'
```

I need to know what am I doing wrong and what is the correct way to do it.

Thanks!

Comment: please first conver main dictionary to json string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
NSString *strJson = @"your json string here";
```

if you don't have json string then first convert your NSDictionary into JSON String

```
NSData *data = [jsonStr dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
id json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:nil];
```

Comment: Thanks, but used org.simple.json library and its working fine

Comment: earlier I used org.json and now I am using org.simple.json.

Comment: after changing the libraries I am not getting an error, thanks for the help!